# Mac Infection via Website Visiting?

Tags: mac, virus

Is it possible for a mac to get infected by just visiting a URL?

I was searching for someone's profile when suddenly the URL browser showed a couple of re-directions and then my macbook started beeping.

Ever since, the ActivityMonitor is also showing high cpu activity...

I do not wish to download any mac cleaners or other software, but I wonder if I could check my mac myself to see if there is malicious software or something like that?

Are there any folders I should look at to see if there is something in them that is not supposed to be there?

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer given the broad nature.  Everything is vague from the site to what exactly in Activity Monitor, to what exactly the issue is.  Please edit with *specifics* (i.e. a screen cap of Activity Monitor) - help us help you.

Comment: You are right. I should have immediately captured a screenshot of the Activity Monitor, but now it has all settled down. Regarding the site, as soon as I noticed the quick re-directions and the sudden beep, I quickly did a cmd+Q to exit, so I have no clue what site I was taken to. So, I guess now I can only ask if there are any locations on a mac where I could just visually inspect to see if there is a dodgy file/folder that is not supposed to be there; something that is perhaps well known to be a worm or virus directory? Sorry, I have no more details...

Comment: The beeping doesn't mean that you have a virus. Any webpage can play audio, and can play audio that sounds like the system beep. Do you remember if you had your speakers turned up while on the site?

Comment: Yes, they were on. The beeping alone did not concern me. The cpu activity afterward did. I am reluctant to download any cleaners though. Is there one that is universally accepted and used, and perhaps supported/endorsed by Apple, without slowing down the machine? Google search returns loads... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s possible, no it’s not likely.

You should do one of three things:

- get malware anti bytes for Mac and scan for malware
- make your user non administrator if you might be browsing places you don’t trust
- reinstall the os if you feel you are very compromised and possibly get help from someone on cleaning

Chances are, a reboot is all you need to do unless beeping and high cpu persist.